# python - calculating smma (smoothed moving average)

Tags: python-3.x, pine-script, moving-average

I'm trying to program the smma (smoothed moving average) in Python. I take the formula from a pine script in tradingview.

```
smma =  0.0
smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
```

So, when there's no previous smma value, we're supposed to take the simple moving average of (src,length). The next calculations is according to (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length. smmma[1] being the previous smma value.

This is my code:

```
def smma(src, length):
    smma = 0.0
    dataLength = len(src)
    lookbackPeriod = dataLength - length

    #first value of smma is the sma of src and length
    #Convert list to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(src, columns = ['hl2'])
    smma = df.rolling(window=length).mean()
    smma = float(smma.iloc[-1])
    log.info(f"First smma value = {smma}")

    lookbackPeriod = dataLength - length + 1 #calculate smma for the other values
    while (lookbackPeriod < dataLength):
        smma = (smma * (length - 1) + float(src[lookbackPeriod])) / length
        log.info(f"lookback = {lookbackPeriod} src[lookbackPeriod] = {src[lookbackPeriod]} smma = {smma}")
        lookbackPeriod = lookbackPeriod + 1
    return smma
```

The output for a period length of 5 looks like this:

```
[2021-11-07 12:26:21,701] First smma value = 61842.0
[2021-11-07 12:26:21,701] lookback = 196 src[lookbackPeriod] = 61817.25 smma = 61837.05
[2021-11-07 12:26:21,701] lookback = 197 src[lookbackPeriod] = 61883.5 smma = 61846.340000000004
[2021-11-07 12:26:21,701] lookback = 198 src[lookbackPeriod] = 61867.75 smma = 61850.621999999996
[2021-11-07 12:26:21,702] lookback = 199 src[lookbackPeriod] = 61838.0 smma = 61848.0976
```

src is in my case a list of 200 values.
When I compare the value of the first smma with a sma, then it is correct compared to the value on Tradingview. The value for the final value of the smma is not correct compared to what I see on Tradingview. (I take in this case as source (high+low)/2 instead of close, but still, it doesn't show it correctly when I take that as a source in Tradingview)

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm, I believe your implementation is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. You just need to calculate on a big enough sample size. In my case, calculating the smma for a period of 5 should not be run on 5 data points, but on a size of 200 I have the correct value.
So, calculate the simple moving average on your first 5 data points and then start the smma calculation for the remaining 195 data points. The last value for the smma is the correct one which matches the value in Tradingview.

Answer (score 3):

Calculating SMMA in Python using formula is challenging, but there is an easy alternative you could use any python TA library (such as https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ta.html) and get EMA. SMMA essentially is EMA but just with different length. you can try this in tradingview insert SMMA and EMA, and change lengths as mentioned in screensnip here. you will observe that SMMA and EMA overlaps here.

[image]

ideally, where SMMA length x, set EMA length to x*2-1 (of course except for length 1), you will get exact results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was struggling with the same issue - SMMA values calculated by mine code vs TradingView values on chart.

The problem is that you can find various formulas how to calculate SMMA, for example: 
[chartmill.com](https://www.chartmill.com/documentation/technical-analysis-indicators/217-MOVING-AVERAGES-%7C-The-Smoothed-Moving-Average-%28SMMA%29) 
[fxcorporate.com](http://www.fxcorporate.com/help/MS/NOTFIFO/i_SMMA.html)

Honestly, so far I was not able to get exact TradingView results, but I found [chartmill](https://www.chartmill.com/documentation/technical-analysis-indicators/217-MOVING-AVERAGES-%7C-The-Smoothed-Moving-Average-%28SMMA%29) results closest to TradingView ones.

I try to implement SMMA in Java as an extension for [ta4j library](https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j). Please find my recent results below. Hopefully you find it helpful and together we will find correct implementation:

```
public class SMMAIndicator extends RecursiveCachedIndicator<Num> {

/**
 * N - Number of periods, over which the indicator is calculated.
 */
private final int barCount;
private final Num n;

/**
 * Usually ClosePriceIndicator
 */
private final Indicator<Num> indicator;

/**
 * SMA to calculate 1st SMMA period per index
 */
private final SMAIndicator smaIndicator;

public SMMAIndicator(Indicator<Num> indicator, int barCount) {
    super(indicator.getBarSeries());
    this.barCount = barCount;
    this.n = numOf(barCount);
    this.indicator = indicator;
    this.smaIndicator = new SMAIndicator(indicator, barCount);
}

@Override
public Num calculate(int index) {
    var i = max(0, index - barCount + 1);

    if (i == 0) {
        return smaIndicator.getValue(index);
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        var nMinus1 = n.minus(numOf(1));
        var smma0 = getValue(index - 1);
        var input = indicator.getValue(index);
        return smma0.multipliedBy(nMinus1).plus(input).dividedBy(n);
    }

    var prevSmma = getValue(index - 1);
    var prevSum = prevSmma.multipliedBy(n);
    return prevSum.minus(prevSmma).plus(indicator.getValue(index)).dividedBy(n);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that chartmill link explains the formula a bit better. So, I've changed the code a bit. Since my list contains 200 items and I want to know for example SMMA(5), then I go back to item 191 and calculate the average of 191, 192, 193, 194 and 195. Then the SMMA for the remaining 4 items (list index up to 199). It comes close to Tradingview, but indeed, not exactly the same.

Comment: @Greggy when you have 200 data points, and you want to calculate SMMA(5) on the 200th data point, what is the meaning of first SMMA(5) value? Is it on 1st data point, 5th data point, or 195th data point ? It's very confusing to understand this formula

Answer (score 0):

This code work for my

```
def calculate_smma(src, length):
smma = pd.Series(index=src.index, dtype=float)

for i in range(len(src)):
    if pd.isna(smma.iloc[i - 1]):
        smma.iloc[i] = src.iloc[:i + 1].mean()
    else:
        smma.iloc[i] = (smma.iloc[i - 1] * (length - 1) + src.iloc[i]) / length

return smma
```